# Function output as integer (TypeError: must be str, not int)

Tags: python, function, integer, output

I am new on programming and started with Python.
I am trying to write a function with an output that looks like "|1|2"

### If I am writing code as:

```
def xbrd(int1,int2):
    print("|"+int1+"|"+int2)
```

---

Output has an error >> TypeError: must be str, not int

### full detail below:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-43-e3178cb02070> in <module>()
----> 1 xbrd(1,2) <ipython-input-42-07f9ddd5a2b8> in xbrd(int1, int2)
      1 def xbrd(int1,int2):
----> 2     print("|"+int1+"|"+int2) TypeError: must be str, not int
```

---

NOW if write it as below then I am getting desired output.

```
def xbrd(int1,int2):
    print(f'|{int1}|{int2}')
```

---

**Does this mean in later code output is coming as string ? what I need to get output as integer?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because all of the string formatting ways make it into `str` since they gonna become in the string, example:

```
>>> a=1
>>> f'{a}'
'1'
>>> '%s'%a
'1'
>>> '{}'.format(a)
'1'
>>>
```

So your code can work, so here are the codes with all the formatting ways i mentioned above:

```
def xbrd(int1,int2):
    print(f'|{int1}|{int2}')
```

---

```
def xbrd(int1,int2):
    print('|%s|%s'%(int1,int2))
```

---

```
def xbrd(int1,int2):
    print('|{}|{}'.format(int1,int2))
```

Note that there is another way, without string formatting or anything, similar to first example, but it is just converting the integers to string using `str`:

```
def xbrd(int1,int2):
    print("|"+str(int1)+"|"+str(int2))
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I think my take away from this is any print output gonna to be 'str'

Comment: @yogeshmalhotra Good that this is right, happy to help, 